# What does the doctor mean by "plastic" in Room?

Tags: plot-explanation, room

After the escape, a doctor tells Ma that it’s a good thing she got Jack out while he was still "plastic".

What does he mean by *plastic*?

Comment: Based on context, I'm reasonably sure he means while the child's mind is still malleable and able to cope with change. An older child (or young adult) would have become institutionalised and coped very poorly with such a dramatic shift in circumstances.

Comment: [Plasticity in the context of psychology](http://psychology.about.com/od/biopsychology/f/brain-plasticity.htm) - which includes using the word "plastic" as an adjective - means the ability of our brains to physically adapt to changes, particularly physical damage and trauma, but also in response to experience. Brains are more "plastic" (greater plasticity) when people are younger

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The scene as described [in the script](http://a24awards.com/film/room/room_script.pdf?ref_=ac_ac_ac_acd_scr_i_1) takes place as follows:

> **DR. MITTAL** Have you thought any more about what we discussed this
> morning?
>
> **MA** Thanks for the offer but we’re going to go home.
>
> **DR. MITTAL** You know my view. After what you’ve experienced, and to assess
> Jack properly. And just to soften the transition -
>
> **MA** (interrupting)
> Nothing happened to Jack.
>
> **DR. MITTAL** I understand, but even at a
> cognitive-sensory level - depth perception, auditory processing ...
>
> **MA**
> But he’s OK, right?
>
> **DR. MITTAL** The most important thing you did was to
> get him out ***while he’s still plastic***.
>
> **JACK** (whispers to Ma) I’m not
> plastic.
>
> **DR. MITTAL** What’s that, Jack.
>
> **MA** He says he’s real, not
> plastic. Mittal laughs.
>
> **DR. MITTAL** I can’t argue with that, Jack. Real
> and very brave.

So it's pretty clear from the context that the doctor is using *plastic* to imply Jack was young enough that he could cope with leaving "Room" and deal with the world outside (as opposed to an older child or adult who may not be able to cope with this).

To quote one of the definitions of *plastic" from the [Merriam-Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plastic):

> capable of being made into different shapes

That describes the Dr's view quite well.

Comment: Wouldn't "plasticine" have been a better word?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat check comment by user568458